# Worklight 6.2 - Duplicate Symbols when importing a framework compiled with ARMv7s ARM64

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, sqlcipher, arm64

Does Worklight 6.2 support frameworks built with architecture slice ARMv7s ARM64?

When I try to link one of them I get duplicate symbols on XCode. 
Is it necessary to recompile the SQLCipher?

Answer (score 0):

iOS 64bit support is a recent addition to the following available Worklight releases:

- Worklight 6.0
- Worklight 6.1
- Worklight Foundation 6.2
- MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3

For 6.3, which was released on December 5th, this is already available.
For 6.0/6.1/6.2, you need to download the latest available iFix per the following IBM tech note:

- [Support for iOS 64-bit code with IBM Mobile Foundation, IBM Worklight, and IBM Worklight Foundation, and IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21692883)
- Accompanying blog post: [iOS 64 bit support](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2014/12/17/ios-64-bit-support/)